# Proving that $A_4/(C_2\times C_2) \cong C_3$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Is there a quick way to see that $A_4/(C_2\times C_2) \cong C_3$ without having to write down the entire Cayley table?

I think the fact that any element in $A_4$ is either a 3-cycle like $(abc)$ or a disjoint double transposition like $(ab)(cd)$ might help, but I'm not sure how to set up the bijection between $A_4/(C_2\times C_2)$ and $C_3$

**Edit**: Also, can $A_4$ be written as a semi-direct product of $C_2\times C_2$ and $C_3$?

This [Wiki page](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Klein_four-subgroup_of_alternating_group:A4) mentions it as a fact but I'm not sure how to prove such a result elegantly. Even some hints might help!

Comment: There isn't any way, quick or not.  That is because $A_4$ is not isomorphic to $(C_2\times C_2)\times C_3$.

Comment: @Batominovski The Wiki page I linked says: "It is a normal subgroup and the **quotient group** is isomorphic to cyclic group: Z3". By it, they're referring to the subgroup $V_4$ of $A_4$. So at least, $A_4/(C_2\times C_2) \cong C_3$ must be true.

Comment: That doesn't mean that $A_4\cong V_4\times C_3$.  It simply means $A_4/V_4\cong C_3$.

Comment: But if you want to show $A_4/V_4\cong C_3$, then observe that $A_4$ acts on $\{a,b,c\}$ where $a:=\big\{\{1,2\},\{3,4\}\big\}$, $b:=\big\{\{1,3\},\{2,4\}\big\}$, and $c:=\big\{\{1,4\},\{2,3\}\big\}$.  Show that the kernel of this group action is $V_4$.  (Therefore, $V_4$ is a normal subgroup of $A_4$, whence $A_4/V_4$ is a group of order $\dfrac{12}{4}=3$.)

Comment: Please note that I've edited the question.

Comment: connected : https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3083628

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the original claim that $A_4\cong (C_2\times C_2)\times C_3$ was incorrect, it was not too far from a correct statement, which is that $A_4$ is the semidirect product
$$A_4\cong (C_2\times C_2)\rtimes C_3\,.$$

To show this, let $V_4\cong C_2\times C_2$ be the Sylow $2$-subgroup of $A_4$.  Then, we have a right-splitting short exact sequence of groups:
$$1\to V_4 \to A_4 \to C_3\to 1\,,$$
with a section $C_3\to A_4$ given by $\gamma\mapsto (1\;2\;3)$ if $C_3$ is generated by $\gamma$.

Alternatively, note that
$$V_4=\Big\{1,(1\;2)(3\;4),(1\;3)(2\;4),(1\;4)(2\;3)\Big\}$$
and 
$$Z:=\Big\{1,(1\;2\;3),(1\;3\;2)\Big\}$$
are trivially intersecting subgroups of $A_4$ with $V_4\trianglelefteq A_4$ and $A_4=V_4Z$.  Therefore, $A_4$ is the internal semidirect product of $V_4$ and $Z\cong C_3$.

Comment: Thanks! To prove that it's a semi-direct product and *not* merely a direct product I guess we also have to show that $C_3$ is *not* normal in $A_4$. Does that somehow follow from your answer or could you include that part?

Comment: I didn't say it because it is trivial (but it is a good point to make because this should be checked as a general principle).  If $C_3$ were normal in $A_4$, then $A_4\cong V_4\times C_3$ would be abelian.

Comment: Umm, how can you conclusively say that if $C_3$ were normal in $A_4$ then $A_4$ would be abelian? Could you be a bit more explicit? I'm perhaps missing some theorem here.

Comment: That is simply because direct products of abelian groups are always abelian.  Since $V_4$ and $C_3$ are both abelian, $V_4\times C_3$ is abelian.  However, I think you are looking for something else like this: if $H$ and $K$ are normal subgroups of $G$ such that $H\cap K=\{1\}$ and $HK=G$, then $G\cong H\times K$.  (As oppose to semidirect products, where only one of $H$ or $K$ need be a normal subgroup of $G$.)

Answer (score 2):

There is a reasonable quick way to show that $A_{4} / (\mathbb{Z}_{2} \times \mathbb{Z}_{2}) \cong \mathbb{Z}_{3}$ : Infact you have to notice that $\mathbb{Z}_{2} \times \mathbb{Z}_{2}$ is a normal subgroup of $A_{4}$, so the quotient group will be well define, but the only group of order 3 up to isomorphism is $\mathbb{Z}_{3}$.

On the other hand if $A_{4}$ can't be isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_{2} \times \mathbb{Z}_{2} \times \mathbb{Z}_{3}$, since the second would be abelian but $A_{4}$ is not.

(You can just find two elements that don't commute)

Comment: Thanks a lot! Can $A_4$ be at least written as a semi-direct product of $(\Bbb Z_2 \times \Bbb Z_2)$ and $\Bbb Z_3$ if not a direct product? I mean, if we can show $\Bbb Z_3$ is not normal in $A_4$ we should be able to write it as a semi-direct product.

Comment: @Triskelion Yes it is, you can find some reference to the theorem to use [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semidirect_product)

Answer (score 0):

$V_4=\{e,(12)(34),(13)(24),(14)(23)\}$ contains all the products of two disjoint transpositions that live in $A_4$.  But conjugation preserves cycle structure.  It follows that $V_4\triangleleft A_4$.

The rest is trivial, since we can form the quotient group, and it has order $3$.